# После отправки формы на валидацию пропадает значение даты Datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp, mvc

Здравствуйте. 
Имеется некая строка, в которую нужно ввести Дату. При щелчке на строке вылетает
"Календарь Datepicker", в котором мы выбираем нужную нам дату. При сохранении, если какие-либо поля были некорректно заполнены ,выбранная нами дата в строке обнуляется и приходится ее каждый раз выбирать заново.

Вопрос: каким образом при выборе даты через календарь, дата сохранялась бы в строке независимо от обновления страницы или некорректного заполнения других строк? Просто у меня на форме 10 строк, где нужно вводить даты. И при каждом сохранении даты обнуляются их приходится вводить снова. Заранее спасибо за помощь. Код:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $.datepicker.regional['ru'] = {
            closeText: 'Закрыть',
            prevText: '&#x3c;Пред',
            nextText: 'След&#x3e;',
            currentText: 'Сегодня',
            monthNames: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь',
            'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь',
            'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
            dayNames: ['воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота'],
            dayNamesShort: ['вск', 'пнд', 'втр', 'срд', 'чтв', 'птн', 'сбт'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'],
            weekHeader: 'Не',
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ''
        };
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ru']);
    });
</script>
<div class="editor-field">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#r_birthdate").datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '1950:2010' });

            });
</script>
```

*Строка, где нужно выбрать дату.*

```
<input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="Требуется поле Дата рождения" id="r_birthdate" name="r_birthdate">
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.r_birthdate)
```